# Array inside MySQL field?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: users and items. Each item has a user#. So, if I want to find only items associated with a particular user I can:

> SELECT * FROM items WHERE user_id = "$user_id";

But if there are thousands of items, searching through the table will take forever, right?

Is there a better way to go about doing this? Maybe a way to store all item numbers associated with a user into a field in the users table?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Does every item has exactly one user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't take forever.  This is how it should be done, even if there were millions of records.

I noticed you quoted the user_id value... Isn't it a number field?  The quotes are not needed.

Obviously the user_id should be an indexed field.

Comment: It's part of a php string:
$query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
This would work without the quotes?

Comment: Yeah... `$query = "select * from items where user_id = $user_id";`  and make sure you're sanitizing that variable so it cannot be sql injection.

Answer (score 3):

Keep your current structure but add an index on `user_id`. This will mean that there is no need to search through "thousands of items" when doing lookups on this column.

Storing multiple values in a single column (a violation of [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)) would be a step backwards as it would drastically reduce the efficiency of the opposite query to do lookups by `item_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Databases (not just MySQL) are pretty fast when searching. So it will take only few milliseconds to find such a row even in millions records. Databases use "indexes" for this - so if the column "user_id" is not primary key, then create index on user_id. Otherwise it could be slow.